# Zend framework 2: redirect toRoute shortcircuit not triggering

Tags: php, redirect, zend-framework2

Normally this is not the kind of question that I would ask, as I expect that it is something stupid that I am missing, but in debugging I have found some really weird behaviour that really has me stumped.

To describe the setup in which the (suspected) error occurs: I have a basic CRUD-controller (or the preferred NERD in my case) where I have four actions:

- new
- edit
- read
- delete

The read, edit and delete actions require an object, say a blogpost, and the url called by a route like `/post/read/[:id]` an id needs to be supplied. The first thing I do in each of these actions is to check that (a) the id parameter is set and that (b) the id corresponds to a valid entity stored in the database (I am using Doctrine 2 as mapper). If either (a) or (b) fails, I immediately return and redirect to the index action:

```
 return $this->redirect()->toRoute('post/index');
```

I do the checks in a separate public function in the same controller to prevent code duplication.

## The Code:

```
<?php

namespace Blog\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\FlashMessenger as FlashMessenger;

class PostController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function editAction()
    {
        $post_id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');
        $post    = $this->validatePostId($post_id);

        // Create/Validate forms and persist/flush

        return array(
            'post' => $post,
            'form' => $form
        );
    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {
        $post_id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');
        $post    = $this->validatePostId($post_id);

        // Remove post from database
        $this->getBlogService()->deletePost($post);
        $this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage('Post successfully deleted');
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('post');
    }

    public function readAction()
    {
        $post_id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');
        $post    = $this->validatePostId($post_id);

        return array(
            'post' => $post
        );
    }

    /**
     * Checks if $id from url is set and tries to find the corresponding post
     */
    public function validatePostId($post_id)
    {        
        if (!$post_id) {
            $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage('Invalid post id');
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('post');
        }

        $post = $this->getBlogService()->getPostById($post_id);

        if ($post == NULL) {
            $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage('Invalid post id');
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('post');
        }

        return $post;
    }
}
```

## The Problem

This code works perfectly **except for `readAction()`** where even if the two conditionals in `validatePostId()` fire, the `return $this->redirect()` is somehow not triggered and the application renders the view and the subsequent errors with invalid accessing of a non-object `$post`.

I have checked a thousand times and the conditionals that check for a valid `$post` are really entered and so I am sure that the redirect is called. A hint that I found, but can not explain, is the following. If I change the read action to the following, just adding a single line:

```
public function readAction()
{
    $post_id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');
    $post    = $this->validatePostId($post_id);

    $form    = $this->getPostForm()->bind();

    return array(
        'post' => $post
    );
}
```

the problem disappears and the application neatly redirects. This does not make sense however. The line just calls a public function in the controller that instantiates a form and as far as I can see this should have no effect. It gets worse, if I remove the `->bind()` call from that line, the old problem is back again. So all I have been able to figure out is that the difference in the actions seems to be the absence of any extra code between the call to `validatePostId()` and the return of the view, which should not really matter...

## Edit:

update, if I directly use the code of the `validatePostId()` function in the `readAction()` the problem also disappears:

```
public function readAction()
{
    $post_id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');
    $post    = $this->validatePostId($post_id);

    if (!$post_id) {
        $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage('Invalid post id');
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('post');
    }

    $post = $this->getBlogService()->getPostById($post_id);

    if ($post == NULL) {
        $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage('Invalid post id');
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('post');
    }

    return array(
        'post' => $post
    );
}
```

Comment: I wonder about testing empty() rather than ==NULL.

Comment: `empty()` does not make a difference

Comment: the most recent edit suggests something is going wrong in $post = $this->getBlogService()->getPostById($post_id); In the original code, if you var_dump($post_id) and var_dump($post) just before the return, and they are both still null, I am stumped. Perhaps something goes wrong after the redirect -i.e. wherever route('post') goes.  +1 for your avatar, btw

Comment: Well that makes two of us, `var_dump($post)` just before the return dumps `NULL` (obviously, else it shouldn't have entered the `if` to begin with). Thanks for your comments though

Comment: just thinking... what happens if you validated in the constructor? Or validate in a different class and inject a validated post object into $this->post?  I also notice you first stated the route to 'post/index', but the other examples route to 'post'.  Sorry wish i could be more help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The act of calling `$this->redirect()` in your controller doesn't automatically redirect to a new location, it just returns a `Response` object which you then need to return from your controller action in order to short circuit the request.

Since you're returning the result of the `redirect()` call from another function, you'll need to first test if the result of that call is a `Response` object and handle it in your controller action...

```
<?php

namespace Blog\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\FlashMessenger as FlashMessenger;

use Zend\Stdlib\ResponseInterface as Response;

class PostController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function readAction()
    {
        $post_id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');
        $post    = $this->validatePostId($post_id);

        // check to see if post validation returned a Response 
        if ($post instanceof Response) {
            // redirect...
            return $post;
        }

        return array(
            'post' => $post
        );
    }

    /**
     * Checks if $id from url is set and tries to find the corresponding post
     */
    public function validatePostId($post_id)
    {        
        if (!$post_id) {
            $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage('Invalid post id');
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('post');
        }

        $post = $this->getBlogService()->getPostById($post_id);

        if ($post == NULL) {
            $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage('Invalid post id');
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('post');
        }

        return $post;
    }
}
```

Comment: Helpful explanantion, thanks. I changed the check in the action you proposed on whether `$post` is an instance of Response to checking if it is an object though and it works